# "Show active learning suggestions" button locked in qnamaker.ai

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I created a KB on Azure QnA Service via qnamaker.ai. After activating the Active Learning function within the service settings I was able to activate the suggestions using the "Show active learning suggestions" button within the editor.

My problem now is that the button is currently no longer usable.
It is locked and shows the prohibition sign on mouseover.
Every time I publish the kb the button gets unlocked for less than five seconds and then, in real-time, gets locked again.

The problem has been going on for several days.
I also tried to solve recreating the KB on a different tenant or using other types of contents (link instead of Excel file).

The version of the runtime is 5.44.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Mario Ierardi The most likely reason that you seeing this as disabled is that you do not have any active learning suggestions for your KB. [Active learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/active-learning-suggestions#how-active-learning-works) suggestions are triggered based on the scores of the top few answers returned by QnA Maker. If the score differences between QnA pairs that match the query lie within a small range, then the query is considered a possible suggestion (as an alternate question) for each of the possible QnA pairs. Once you accept the suggested question for a specific QnA pair, it is rejected for the other pairs. You need to remember to save and train, after accepting suggestions.

In short, Please ensure you use the KB after adding it with queries to your KB which match your existing Questions or answers and this should trigger the suggestions.